# Is a college degree needed to get a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, usa, europe, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

I'm an Indian, 22 years old and dropped out of my college this year. I want to know if it's hard to get a tourist visa to Europe or USA if I do not have a college degree.

Answer (score 11):

No, having a college degree does not affect the process of obtaining a *tourist visa* to either Schengen area or US. In both cases the most important thing is proving strong ties with your home country. This includes a bank account with a decent balance, an employment letter etc. Take a look at the requirements to obtain a Schengen visa from the [French Consulate](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/delhishortstayvisa.html) or from the [US embassy](http://mumbai.usconsulate.gov/tourism-/-business.html) and as you can see none of them requires a college degree. The US visa totally depends on the interview you will have at the embassy, anyway proving that you only intend to travel for tourism purposes is the strongest supporter to get the visa.

P.S. Not having a college degree does affect you in an indirect way! you will not have a nicer job which will lead to a worse bank account which will lead to visa rejection, unless daddy has a nice bank account ;)

Comment: You also don't need a degree to become an entrepreneur. You just have to start at the bottom.

Comment: O@hippietrail or a football player, but the college degree makes things easier.

Comment: Getting a degree also makes it easy to get old instead of doing stuff d-; Not that I'm advising anyone to drop out, but I am encouraging people who already dropped out or otherwise won't get a degree not to despair.

Comment: @hippietrail I dropped out and I am doing just fine. So I somehow agree with you.

Comment: I never even dropped in. All I know about degrees is that outside right now there are fewer than zero of them d-: But we digress! Enough with these chatty comments. OP: Don't worry - just go get your visa, if not for EU or USA then anywhere else you like.

Comment: @Halabi actually, for American Football, college is *de facto* required to play in the NFL.